# Scala: Linked Actor doesn't terminate

Tags: scala, actor

In scala.actors (not Akka!) I want a sending-only actor to terminate as soon as another actor terminates. I believe the scala.actors.Actor.link should be appropriate but it doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
import scala.actors.Actor
import scala.actors.Actor._

object Main extends App {
  class Receiver extends Actor {
    def act() {
      val sender = new Sender(self)
      sender.start()
      var i = 0
      while (i < 3) {
        receive {
          case 'ping => println('pong); i += 1
        }
      }
      exit('stop)
    }
  }
  class Sender(receiver: Actor) extends Actor {
    def act() {
      link(receiver) // <-- !!!
      while (true) {
        Thread sleep 500
        println("ping")
        receiver ! 'ping
      }
    }
  }
  val receiver = new Receiver
  receiver.start()
}
```

Here's the result:

```
ping
'pong
ping
'pong
ping
'pong
ping
ping
ping
ping
ping
ping
ping
ping
```

The sender won't stop sending. Why?

Comment: How can it ever exit the `while (true)` loop?